# retrieving the data from the table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let us say you have a Table with

```
Employees (FName, LName, DeptNo, Age, DOB)
```

and you have a Table called

```
Dept(DeptNo, Department Name)
```

The Challenge is that some of the Employees records do not have any Department No Specified.
I want you to retrieve the List of all Employees along with their Department Name. So what would the Query Look Like.

Answer (score 3):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT
    e.FName,
    e.LName,
    COALESCE(d.DepartmentName, 'NA') AS DepartmentName
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN Dept d
    ON d.DeptNo = e.DeptNo;
```